# Scholarly debates and arguments with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was wondering if there is a TikZ library to diagram scholarly debates. For example, dark grey nodes constitute an argument for thesis (7), while light grey nodes are reasons to resist that argument.

[image]

Comment: No library I am aware of, just need to define styles that you want applied to the nodes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not complete but I've kept the icing on the cake. Some remarks : `outer sep=1mm` is used to get the same position of the arrows. Perhaps it's better to define the sign + and the slash with tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{dark/.style={circle,text=white,fill=darkgray,draw=black,font=\small, minimum size= 8 mm,outer sep=1mm},
light/.style={circle,text=white,fill=gray,draw=black,font=\small, minimum size= 8 mm},
empty/.style={circle, minimum size= 8 mm,outer sep=1mm},
}   

\newcommand{\add}[3]{%
\node [dark] (#1) at (#3) {#1};
\node [text=black] at ([shift= {(1cm,0mm)}]#3) {$+$};
\node [dark] (#2) at ([shift= {(2cm,0mm)}]#3) {#2};
\draw[line width=.8pt] ([shift= {(-4mm,0mm)}]#1.south) -- ([shift= {(4mm,0mm)}]#2.south) coordinate[pos=.5](m);
\node[empty] (end) at ([shift= {(0mm,-2cm)}]m.south)  {};
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (m) -- (end);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \add{2}{3}{0,0}
  \add{4}{1}{end}
  \add{5}{6}{end}
  \node[dark] at (end) {7};
  \node[light](9) at ([shift= {(-3cm,0mm)}]4) {9};
  \draw[line width=.8pt,->] (9) -- (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]